Error in "Principles of Algebraic Geometry" by Griffiths and Harris
At page $148$ of "Introduction to Algebraic Geometry", Griffiths and Harris define a positive line bundle as a line bundle $L\to M$ with a metric such that $(i/2\pi)\Theta$ is a positive $(1,1)$-form, $\Theta$ being the curvature form of the metric.
The immediate next Proposition states:

If $\omega$ is any real, close $(1,1)$-form with $[\omega]=c_1(L)\in H^2_{dR}(M)$, then there exists a metric connection on $L$ with curvature form $\Theta=(i/2\pi)\omega$.
Thus $L$ is positive if and only if its Chern class may be represented by a positive form in $H^2_{dR}(M)$.

Here's my question: shouldn't the Proposition read $\Theta= \color{red}{(2\pi/i)}\omega$?
This doubt came to me because if $\Theta=(i/2\pi)\omega$, then $(i/2\pi)\Theta= -(1/2\pi)^2w$, thus $L$ would be positive if and only if its Chern class is represented by a negative form. Also following the proof of the Proposition (which I don't find very clear, that's why I'm asking), it seems to me that the authors prove that  $\Theta=(2\pi/i)\omega$.
Can someone confirm? I'm aware of this list, but I haven't found this mentioned. Thanks in advance!

Yes, you're right. A line bundle $L$ is positive if the cohomology class $c_1(L)$ is represented by a positive $(1,1)$-form. But $c_1(L) = \left[\frac{\sqrt{-1}}{2\pi}\Theta\right]$, where $\Theta$ is the curvature form. So, unwinding this, there should be a connection with whose curvature satisfies $\frac{\sqrt{-1}}{2\pi}\Theta = \omega$, yes. I started compiling an informal and incomplete list of errata 40+ years ago, but there's never been a definitive compilation of which I'm aware.

@TedShifrin Thank you so much for your response!
